# GCP - Deploy API and frontend on subdomain and domain respectively

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

To get started, I create an `Google App Engine` where I deploy on my custom domain (which we will refer to as: `mysite.ms`) both the API and the frontend. The API are written in `nodejs` with `Express` ant the frontend is a `React` application. This is my `app.yml` file that I use for the deploy:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

resources:
  cpu: .5
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10

handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: www/build/index.html
    upload: www/build/index.html

  - url: /
    static_dir: www/build
```

Now, what I want is to separte the element. On the `mysite.ms` domain deploy only the `React` application and on a subdomain `sub.mysite.ms` the `API`. Since the domain was taken over on freenom, to create a subdomain I add a new `DNS` of type `CNAME` with value `sub.mysite.ms` and target the original domain `mysite.ms`.

Is it possible to create these separate deployments using only the Google App Engine and a single `app.yml` file or do you need to use some other tool and separate the files?

How do you advise me to proceed? Since I can't find anything clear online, could you give me some tips to solve these problems?

## UPDATE

I have read the documentation that you provided me and I some doubts regarding it. First of all, how can I create different services? Because I create this (but most probably wrong) `dispatch.yml`:

```
dispatch:
  - url: "mysite.ms/*"
    service: default

  - url: "sub.mysite.ms/*"
    service: api
```

but when I deploy with this command `gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml`, I get an error because it can't find the module 'api'. 
In the previus version, in my `server.js` I have this code to handle the `React`:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'www', 'build')));
app.get('*', (req, res) => { res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'www', 'build', 'index.html')); });
```

1. Should I keep these two lines of code even if I split the frontend and the api on different domain?
2. Shoud I add the `sub.mysite.ms` to the custom domain area in the section on Google App Engine?
3. Should I keep the file `app.yml` even if I have the `dispath.yaml`?

Comment: You need to use `services` and `dispatch.yaml`. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/an-overview-of-app-engine#services https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/reference/dispatch-yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, it is not possible to deploy more than one service using the same `yaml` file. Let's suppose you may want to deploy two services: `api` and `frontend`. Let's say you want the `frontend` service to be default one so everytime everybody access to `mysite.ms`, they will see the `frontend` service.

Let's say you have the `app.yaml` file as follows for the `frontend` service:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

as you can notice, there is no the `service` property in your `app.yaml`. In the `app.yaml` file [reference doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml#general) you will see the following:

> `service: service_name`
>
> Required if creating a service. Optional for the default service. Each service and each version must have a name. A name can contain numbers, letters, and hyphens. In the flexible environment, the combined length of service and version cannot be longer than 48 characters and cannot start or end with a hyphen. Choose a unique name for each service and each version. Don't reuse names between services and versions.

Because there is not the `service` property, the deploy will be set to the `default` service. Now let's say you have another `yaml` file, in particular the `api.yaml` to deploy the `api` service. Here's an example:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
service: api

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

You will see that I've added the `service` property and when you deploy using `gcloud app deploy api.yaml`, the deploy will create the service `api`.

Finally, after creating the services you will be able to deploy the `dispatch.yaml` file you've created.

Some advices for you:

- Is a good practice to assign the `app.yaml` file to the default service. For the other services, you may want to name the files according to the service to deploy with such file i.e. `api.yaml`, `backend.yaml`, `api_external.yaml`, etc.
- You can deploy deploy both services using `gcloud app deploy path/to/service1 path/to/service2 path/to/service3 ...` or you can do it individually for better debugging in case there could be some issues.
- Since you're using the Flex environment, the `handlers` property are [not supported](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml). If you add them, those are ignored.
- Check the right documents for the environment you use. [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml), [`dispatch.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/dispatch-yaml), [general docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/how-to).