# Main domains on Vercel or Netlify but sub domains on LAMP Hosting platform not showing

Tags: dns, hosting, netlify, vercel

I am currently hosting Gatsby or Next JS websites on Vercel or Netlify but my email accounts go through a traditional hosting control panel platform (like Digital Ocean or Linode with cPanel or similar). I also have sub domains sometimes that might include a PHP script or CMS like WordPress.

So far, I have managed to set up `domain.com` to go to the Hosting, and from there set up an `Alias` and `CNAME` that redirect to the site hosted on Vercel.

| @ | ALIAS | 10800 | domain.netlify.com. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| www | CNAME | 10800 | domain.netlify.com. |
| www | CNAME |  | [cname.vercel-dns.com](http://cname.vercel-dns.com) |
| @ | A |  | 76.76.21.21 |

My last hurdle is a sub domain at `sub.domain.com` just shows a broken page on Vercel.
How do I set it so that any sub domains are landing on my PHP Hosting platform?

[DNS Flow visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If3vl.png)

Comment: The answer on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63971925/vercel-and-pythonanywhere-deploy-separtly-frontend-and-backend-on-domain-and-s/64001163#64001163) can help. But it is not entirely clear what the problem with your setup is.

Comment: Even the flow is confusing as it is mixing DNS records with the protocol layer (HTTP) given the business rules.

Comment: Thanks @paulogdm - The problem is if I redirect a domain to say Netlify or Vercel, how do I also have sub domains directed to a traditional hosting platform? Also the email accounts will go through that hosting platform also.

Comment: All of that is possible with DNS records:
`@` => It can go to Vercel using A records
`www` => It can go to Vercel using A records
Email => Just use MX records
Subdomains => Use A records to point to the right provider.