Deploy both Frontend and Backend on same domain on vercel
I am using Express + Type script for Backend. And vite + React for frontend.
I want to deploy both frontend and backend to deploy in same domain in vercel. to Support cookies
Project Structure
|- server
|    |- src/server.ts
|    |- package.json
|
|- client
|    |- src/
|    |- package.json
|
|- vercel.json


vercel.json
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "server/src/server.ts",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    },
    {
      "src": "client/package.json",
      "use": "@vercel/static-build",
      "config": {
        "distDir": "dist",
        "buildCommand": "npm run build"
      }
    }
  ],
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/api/(.*)",
      "destination": "server/src/server.ts"
    },
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "destination": "client/dist/index.html"
    }
  ]
}

Vercel Deployment Image

It builds both the frontend and backend perfectly without errors, but the both frontend and backend are not working, i mean can't accessible. this is url of my deployment: https://single-host.vercel.app. it just shows 404 error.

Console Logs of The Deployment Domain
Build Logs
vite v6.0.3 building for production...
transforming...
✓ 93 modules transformed.
rendering chunks...
computing gzip size...
dist/registerSW.js                0.13 kB
dist/manifest.webmanifest         0.33 kB
dist/index.html                   0.78 kB │ gzip:  0.40 kB
dist/assets/index-DOKYIi0D.css    0.88 kB │ gzip:  0.48 kB
dist/assets/index-5Zs-5n5D.js   214.14 kB │ gzip: 72.70 kB
✓ built in 2.67s
PWA v0.21.1
mode      generateSW
precache  6 entries (210.88 KiB)
files generated
  dist/sw.js
  dist/workbox-5ffe50d4.js
Installing dependencies...
up to date in 1s
23 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
Using TypeScript 5.7.2 (local user-provided)
Build Completed in /vercel/output [21s]
Deploying outputs...
Deployment completed
Uploading build cache [36.13 MB]...
Build cache uploaded: 607.56ms

package.json of backend
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "start.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -r dist && tsc",
    "dev": "nodemon src/server.ts",
    "start": "node ./dist/server.js",
    "vercel": "rm -r dist && npm run build && vercel --prod",
    "ts.check": "tsc --project tsconfig.json"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}

package.json of frontend
{
  "name": "client",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc -b && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.7.9",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-icons": "^5.4.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^7.0.2",
    "vite-plugin-pwa": "^0.21.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.15.0",
    "@types/node": "^22.10.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.4",
    "eslint": "^9.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.14",
    "globals": "^15.12.0",
    "sass": "^1.83.0",
    "typescript": "~5.6.2",
    "typescript-eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "vite": "^6.0.1"
  }
}


Check if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63971925/vercel-and-pythonanywhere-deploy-separtly-frontend-and-backend-on-domain-and-s/64001163#64001163 can help

I am suspecting that issue with your initial vercel.json configuration is that the rewrite rule for the frontend (/) is pointing directly to client/dist/index.html, which only serves the root page and does not handle other routes.
Instead, you should use /(.*) as the source in the rewrite rule for the frontend, so all paths (not just the root) are correctly routed to the React app's static files in the client/dist folder.
After your first deploy is completed, you would need to tell vercel that your backend app is API and you need to serve it as a serverless function, so you update the vercel.json accordingly
NOTE: Check your tsconfig.json file, if your config file has any other value than dist, replace it.
Here's the corrected configuration:
    {
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "server/dist/server.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    },
    {
      "src": "client/package.json",
      "use": "@vercel/static-build",
      "config": {
        "distDir": "dist"
      }
    }
  ],
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/api/(.*)",
      "destination": "server/dist/server.js"
    },
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "destination": "client/dist/$1"
    }
  ]
}

This updated configuration ensures that:
API routes (/api/*) are routed to the Express backend.
All other routes (/(.*)) are correctly routed to the React frontend, allowing client-side routing to handle paths like /about, /home, etc.
This should resolve the 404 error and allow both the frontend and backend to function properly on the same domain. Redeploy and Recheck... Hope it works

not worked, still like before. 404 page while acessing frontend and backend

please is it possible to share your package.json files for both server and client ?

of course i can share but no use of it. because i provide buils in vercel.json file so it does not use scripts from package.json

i included package.json files in my question.

You know the backend must be built before vercel can run it, vercel will try to deploy your server.ts file directly , but it needs the compiled javascript (dist/server.js) instead of the typescript source (src/server.ts)... we can update it like this (I will edit my initial response) and also  for frontend , ensure your vite.config.js outputs the build files correctly to dist, and also if your backend uses cookies, update your server.ts file to include CORS setting

yes i previously  provide by builded  my backend from ts to js. but later i know that, that vercel also supports automatically builds ts to js. i also checked just by hosting backend with typescript directly on vercel. it works. and also  my front end builds the output into dist folder. i checked by seperately hosted it works.
